# ¿Como rellenar un datagrid en Xaml con informacion estatica?

Tags: c#, xaml

Hola mi consulta es la siguiente tengo una planilla con valores una tabla de 50 por 100 con valores que son para que usuario visualice nada mas, a los que quiero pasar a un datagrid en xaml me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma declarando por ejemplo las filas y su contenido en el mismo xaml, ademas las filas también deberían tener un encabezado.Desde ya muchas gracias.